# AVPlayer not playing video file in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am trying to play a video which is stored on my device using the following code. The problem is that I am seeing nothing on the screen, just a white screen.

The value of `filePath` in this case is `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0E87EF09-B87C-443F-9BFB-E9A68AC4A162/Documents/TMRecordedVideos/2015-07-25T18-57-19Z.mov`

```
NSString *filePath = [self.video fileURL];
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

AVAsset *videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:fileUrl];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset];

self.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

self.videoPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.videoPlayer];
[self.videoPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.frame];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.videoPlayerLayer];
[self.videoPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **AVPlayerLayer** for playing video. I used the below code and it worked fine. The URL(in my case **outputFileURL**) is similar to your filePath.

```
AVPlayer *avPlayerq = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:outputFileURL];
avPlayerq.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayerq];
videoLayer.frame= self.view.bounds;
videoLayer.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[avPlayerq play];
```

Hope this may help you to sort out your issue.